# Javascript generated Range Sliders with -/+ buttons not working as expected

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I used javascript to generate a div structure with two range sliders that display their value. Each range slider also has its own -/+ button to add and subtract from the range value. Both range values are then multiplied and displayed as either range value changes. This works perfect for the first set of generated sliders. The second set everything functions accept for the -/+ buttons. On the second set of range sliders the buttons will add two and subtract two from the first set of range sliders. If I add a third generated set of range sliders the buttons in the second set of range sliders will add and subtract two and the first set will add and subtract 3! I have unsuccessfully tried to change how the math from the buttons is performed. Still completely uncertain as to why this is happening.

The end goal here is to have all of the sliders summed up and sent over to python via flask which is why I have the hidden range value, but I haven't made it that far yet.

'''

```
<script> 

count = 0;

divCount = 0;

fDiv = 1;

rCount = 1;

var shingle = document.getElementById("Shingle");
shingle.addEventListener("click", function myFunction() {

//
//
// DIV CONTAINERs AND SLIDERs
// 
// 
//     

// Main Div
// [    ]    

var holderDiv = document.createElement("div")
holderDiv.type = "div";
holderDiv.style.width = "100%";
holderDiv.id = "holderDiv" + rCount;
holderDiv.style.cssFloat = "left"; 
form1.appendChild(holderDiv);

// Inner Holder Div 1
// [ { },  ]  


var innerHolderDiv = document.createElement("div")
innerHolderDiv.type = "div";
innerHolderDiv.style.width = "30%";
innerHolderDiv.id = "innerHolderDiv" + rCount;
innerHolderDiv.style.cssFloat = "left";
holderDiv.appendChild(innerHolderDiv);

// Inner Holder Div II
// [ { }, { } ]  

var innerHolderDivII = document.createElement("div")
innerHolderDivII.type = "div";
innerHolderDivII.id = "innerHolderDiv" + rCount;
innerHolderDivII.style.cssFloat = "left";
innerHolderDivII.style.width = "30%";
holderDiv.appendChild(innerHolderDivII);


// Slider Container 1
// [ { (  ) }, { } ]  

var dv = document.createElement("div");
dv.class = "slidercontrainer";    
dv.style.fontSize = "75px";
dv.id = "shingleSliderDiv" + ++divCount;
++count;
dv.innerHTML = count; 

innerHolderDiv.appendChild(dv); 

// Slider
// [ { ( #myRange1 ) }, { } ]

var range = document.createElement("input");
range.type = "range";
range.min = "1";
range.max = "100";
range.step ="1";
range.value = "0";
range.className = "slider";
range.id = "myRange" + rCount;
range.style.width = "100%";  
range.style.height = "100%";
range.style.background = "#d3d3d3";
range.style.outline = "none";
range.style.opacity = "1";
++rCount;
innerHolderDiv.appendChild(range);

// Slider Hidden Value
// [ { ( #myRange1, myRange1HiddenValue ) }, { } ]


var rangeHidden = document.createElement("input");  
rangeHidden.type = "number"; 
rangeHidden.name = "rangeHiddenName" + count;
rangeHidden.value = "0";
rangeHidden.id = "rangeHidden" + count;
rangeHidden.style.display = "none";
innerHolderDiv.appendChild(rangeHidden);

// plus and minus buttons
// [ { ( -, #myRange1, +, myRange1HiddenValue ) }, { } ]


var minus = document.createElement("input");
minus.type = "button";
minus.id = "minus" + count;  
minus.value = "-1";
minus.style.width = "50px";
minus.style.cssFloat = "left";
minus.style.height = "50px";
minus.style.background = "#d3d3d3";
minus.style.outline = "none"; 
minus.style.opacity = "1";


innerHolderDiv.appendChild(minus);



var plus = document.createElement("input");
plus.type = "button";
plus.id = "plus" + count;
plus.value = "1";
plus.style.width = "50px";
plus.style.cssFloat = "left";
plus.style.height = "50px";
plus.style.background = "#d3d3d3";
plus.style.outline = "none"; 
plus.style.opacity = "1";


innerHolderDiv.appendChild(plus);   






// Slider Div II
// [ { ( -, #myRange1, +, myRange1HiddenValue ) }, { ( ) } ]

var dv = document.createElement("div");
dv.class = "slidercontrainer";  
dv.value = "0";  
dv.style.fontSize = "75px";
dv.id = "shingleSliderDivII" + divCount;
dv.innerHTML = count; 

innerHolderDivII.appendChild(dv); 

// Slider II
// [ { ( -, #myRange1, +, myRange1HiddenValue ) }, { ( #myRange2 ) } ]      

var rangeII = document.createElement("input");
rangeII.type = "range";
rangeII.step = "1";
rangeII.min = "1"; 
rangeII.max = "100"; 
rangeII.value = "0";
rangeII.className = "slider";
rangeII.id = "myRangeII" + count;

innerHolderDivII.appendChild(rangeII);

// Plus and minus Slider II
// [ { ( -, #myRange1, +, myRange1HiddenValue ) }, { ( -, #myRange2, + ) } ]    

var minus2 = document.createElement("input");
minus2.type = "button";
minus2.id = "minusII" + count;
minus2.value = "-1";
minus2.style.width = "50px";
minus2.style.cssFloat = "left";
minus2.style.height = "50px";
minus2.style.background = "#d3d3d3";
minus2.style.outline = "none"; 
minus2.style.opacity = "1";

innerHolderDivII.appendChild(minus2);

var plusII = document.createElement("input");
plusII.type = "button";
plusII.id = "plusII" + count;
plusII.value = "1";
plusII.style.width = "50px";
plusII.style.cssFloat = "left";
plusII.style.height = "50px";
plusII.style.background = "#d3d3d3";
plusII.style.outline = "none"; 
plusII.style.opacity = "1";


innerHolderDivII.appendChild(plusII);

// Final # Div
// [ { ( -, #myRange1, +, myRange1HiddenValue ) }, { ( -, #myRange2, + ) }, { } ]   

var dvFinalCount = document.createElement("div");
dvFinalCount.class = "slidercontrainer";  
dvFinalCount.value = "test";  
dvFinalCount.id = "finalCount" + fDiv;
++fDiv;
dvFinalCount.style.fontSize = "75px"; 
dvFinalCount.style.cssFloat = "left";
dvFinalCount.innerHTML = fDiv; 

holderDiv.appendChild(dvFinalCount); 



var slider = document.getElementsByClassName("slidecontainer"); 

var sliderR


//
//
// SLIDERS MATH 1
//
//


// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)

var range = document.getElementById("myRange1");
range.addEventListener("input", function() {
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDiv1").innerHTML = this.value;
document.getElementById("rangeHidden1").innerHTML = this.value;
}); 

// Minus Button

var minus = document.getElementById("minus1"); 
minus.addEventListener("click", function() { 
document.getElementById("myRange1").value--;
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDiv1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myRange1").value;
document.getElementById("rangeHidden1").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDiv1").value;

var range1 = document.getElementById("myRange1").value;
var range2 = document.getElementById("myRangeII1").value;
var total = range1 * range2;
document.getElementById("finalCount1").innerHTML = total;

});

// Plus Button


var plus = document.getElementById("plus1");
plus.addEventListener("click", function() {  

document.getElementById("myRange1").value++;
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDiv1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myRange1").value;
document.getElementById("rangeHidden1").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDiv1").value;

var range1 = document.getElementById("myRange1").value;
var range2 = document.getElementById("myRangeII1").value;
var total = range1 * range2;  
document.getElementById("finalCount1").innerHTML = total; 

}); 

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider II handle)

var rangeII = document.getElementById("myRangeII1");
rangeII.addEventListener("input", function() {
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDivII1").innerHTML = this.value;
}); 

// Plus2 Button

var plusII = document.getElementById("plusII1");
plusII.addEventListener("click", function() {
document.getElementById("myRangeII1").value++;  
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDivII1").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("myRangeII1").value;
var range1 = document.getElementById("myRange1").value;
var range2 = document.getElementById("myRangeII1").value;
var total = range1 * range2;
document.getElementById("finalCount1").innerHTML = total;

});

// Minus2 Button

var minusII = document.getElementById("minusII1");
minusII.addEventListener("click", function() {
document.getElementById("myRangeII1").value--;
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDivII1").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("myRangeII1").value;
var range1 = document.getElementById("myRange1").value;
var range2 = document.getElementById("myRangeII1").value;
var total = range1 * range2
document.getElementById("finalCount1").innerHTML = total

});

// Update Final # 1 Div on slider1 input

var range1 = document.getElementById('myRange1');
range1.addEventListener("input", function() {
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDiv1").innerHTML = this.value;
var range1 = document.getElementById("myRange1").value;
var range2 = document.getElementById("myRangeII1").value;
var total = range1 * range2;
document.getElementById("finalCount1").innerHTML = total;
});

// Update Final # 1 Div on slider2 input

var rangeII2 = document.getElementById('myRangeII1');
rangeII2.addEventListener("input", function() {
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDivII1").innerHTML = this.value;
var range1 = document.getElementById("myRange1").value;
var range2 = document.getElementById("myRangeII1").value;
var total = range1 * range2;
document.getElementById("finalCount1").innerHTML = total;
});


//
//
// SLIDERS MATH 2
//
//


// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)

var range = document.getElementById("myRange2");
range.addEventListener("input", function() {
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDiv2").innerHTML = this.value;
document.getElementById("rangeHidden2").innerHTML = this.value;
}); 

// Minus Button II

var minus = document.getElementById("minus2"); 
minus.addEventListener("click", function() {
document.getElementById("myRange2").value--;
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDiv2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myRange2").value;
document.getElementById("rangeHidden2").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDiv2").value;

var range1 = document.getElementById("myRange2").value;
var range2 = document.getElementById("myRangeII2").value;
var total = range1 * range2;
document.getElementById("finalCount2").innerHTML = total;

});

// Plus Button II

var plus = document.getElementById("plus2");
plus.addEventListener("click", function() {
document.getElementById("myRange2").value++; 
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDiv2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myRange2").value;
document.getElementById("rangeHidden2").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDiv2").value;

var range1 = document.getElementById("myRange2").value;
var range2 = document.getElementById("myRangeII2").value;
var total = range1 * range2;
document.getElementById("finalCount2").innerHTML = total; 

}); 

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider II handle)

var rangeII = document.getElementById("myRangeII2");
rangeII.addEventListener("input", function() {
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDivII2").innerHTML = this.value;
}); 

// PlusII Button

var plusII = document.getElementById("plusII2");
plusII.addEventListener("click", function() {
document.getElementById("myRangeII2").value++; 
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDivII2").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("myRangeII2").value;
var range1 = document.getElementById("myRange2").value;
var range2 = document.getElementById("myRangeII2").value;
var total = range1 * range2;
document.getElementById("finalCount2").innerHTML = total;

});

// MinusII Button

var minusII = document.getElementById("minusII2");
minusII.addEventListener("click", function() {
document.getElementById("myRangeII2").value--;
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDivII2").innerHTML =  
document.getElementById("myRangeII2").value;
var range1 = document.getElementById("myRange2").value;
var range2 = document.getElementById("myRangeII2").value;
var total = range1 * range2
document.getElementById("finalCount2").innerHTML = total

});

// Update Final # 1 Div on slider1 input

var range1 = document.getElementById('myRange2');
range1.addEventListener("input", function() {
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDiv1").innerHTML = this.value;
var range1 = document.getElementById("myRange2").value;
var range2 = document.getElementById("myRangeII2").value;
var total = range1 * range2;
document.getElementById("finalCount2").innerHTML = total;
});

// Update Final # 1 Div on slider2 input

var rangeII2 = document.getElementById('myRangeII2');
rangeII2.addEventListener("input", function() {
document.getElementById("shingleSliderDiv2").innerHTML = this.value;
var range1 = document.getElementById("myRange2").value;
var range2 = document.getElementById("myRangeII2").value;
var total = range1 * range2;
document.getElementById("finalCount2").innerHTML = total;
});
});
```

'''